# ENCODER-DECODER : Decoder not accepting large string value

Tags: java, binary, bluej, encoder, decoder

Actually I made this program just for fun. It comprises of an encoder and a decoder. The encoder works as follows :

1. user will input a string
2. it will take out each character one by one from the string
3. it will store its ASCII equivalent in a variable
4. will generate a binary equivalent of this ASCII value
5. then it will print this binary equivalent in form of "dots('.')" and "spaces(' ')"
6. there is a DOT for every "one('1')" and a SPACE for every "zero('0')"

The decoder works just in the opposite way. It takes this code from the user, which is in the form of dots and spaces, and prints the corresponding string. Since the ASCII value of characters that I'm working upon range from 32(space) to 126(~), thus the maximum length of the binary equivalent can be 7. Therefore if the length of a binary equivalent is less than 7 the encoder will automatically add required amount of zeroes before the binary equivalent to make the length 7, so that the decoder can easily decode. The decoder works well for the codes of small sentences. But when I try to input the code of a long sentence(such as the one I'm writing) it does not accept in Bluej but accepts it in command-prompt; can anybody tell me why is this happening. Everybody please try this program on command prompt or whatever you guys use. Please suggest any ideas to improve my program and make the code more complicated.

This is the code :

```
import java.io.*;

class ed2 {

    BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    void encode() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        String rs, ren;

        encoder_symbol();
        rs = encode_input();
        ren = encode_find(rs);
        encode_display(ren);
    }

    void decode() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        String rs, rde;

        decoder_symbol();
        rs = decode_input();
        rde = decode_find(rs);
        decode_display(rde);
    }

    void encoder_symbol() throws InterruptedException // just for fun
    {
        System.out.println("********  ***         ***  *********  ************  ******      ********  *****");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("********  ****        ***  *********  ************  ********    ********  *** **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***       *****       ***  ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***       *** **      ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("******    ***  **     ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("******    ***   **    ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***       ***     **  ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***       ***      ** ***  ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("*******   ***       *****  *********  ************  ********    ********  ***   **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("*******   ***        ****  *********  ************  ******      ********  ***    **");
        Thread.sleep(2700);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    void decoder_symbol() throws InterruptedException // just for fun
    {
        System.out.println("******      ********  *********  ************  ******      ********  *****");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("********    ********  *********  ************  ********    ********  *** **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***   ***   ***       ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***    ***  ***       ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***    ***  ******    ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***    ***  ******    ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***    ***  ***       ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("***   ***   ***       ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("********    ********  *********  ************  ********    ********  ***   **");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("******      ********  *********  ************  ******      ********  ***    **");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    String encode_input() throws IOException {
        String s;
        System.out.println("ENTER THE STRING TO BE ENCODED");
        s = obj.readLine();
        return (s);
    }

    String decode_input() throws IOException {
        String s;
        System.out.println("ENTER THE CODE TO BE DECODED");
        s = obj.readLine();
        return (s);
    }

    String encode_find(String s)// converting the string into its binary
                                // equivalent
    {
        int ac, i, j, l, chklen;
        String bc, en = "";
        char ic;
        l = s.length();
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            ic = s.charAt(i); // takes out every character
            bc = "";
            ac = (int) ic; // ASCII value of this character
            while (ac != 0) {
                bc = Integer.toString((ac % 2)) + bc; // converting the ASCII
                                                      // value into binary
                                                      // equivalent
                ac = ac / 2;
            }
            chklen = bc.length();// length of the binary equivalent
            if (chklen < 7) {
                for (j = 1; j <= (7 - chklen); j++) // increasing the length of
                                                    // binary equivalent so that
                                                    // it becomes equal to 7
                {
                    bc = "0" + bc;
                }
            }
            en = en + bc; // concatenating all the binary equivalent into one
                          // string
        }
        return (en);
    }

    String decode_find(String s)// converts binary(i.e. in the form of dots and
                                // space) to decimal
    {
        int f;// for the index of every character of code
        long l, i, j, ac;
        char c;
        String de = "";

        l = s.length();
        f = 0;// index of first caharcter
        for (i = 0; i < (l / 7); i++)// since the length of every binary
                                     // equivalent of a character is 7 therefore
                                     // there will be (length/7) characters in a
                                     // code of length l
        {
            ac = 0;// intializes the decimal(ASCII) equivalent to zero
            for (j = 6; j >= 0; j--)// loop will work 7 times for every binary
                                    // equivalent of a character
            {
                c = s.charAt(f);// takes out every dot or space
                if (c == '.')// it means that c corresponds to 'one'
                {
                    ac = ac + ((int) Math.pow(2, j));// converting binary into
                                                     // decimal(ASCII)
                                                     // equivalent by adding all
                                                     // the powers of 2 which
                                                     // correspond to one('.')
                }
                f++;// increasing the index for next character of binary
                    // equivalent
            }
            de = de + ((char) ac);// converts the ASCII equivalent into
                                  // character and then concatenates it with the
                                  // intitial string
        }
        return (de);
    }

    void encode_display(String en)// displays the code
    {
        int i, l;
        char ic;
        System.out.println("YOUR ENCODED MESSAGE IS :");
        l = en.length();
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            ic = en.charAt(i);
            if (ic == '1')// for every 'one' it will print '.'(dot)
            {
                System.out.print(".");
            } else if (ic == '0')// for every 'zero' it will print ' '(space)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    void decode_display(String de) {
        System.out.println(de);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        char ch;

        ed2 ed = new ed2();

        System.out.println("PRESS 'E' TO ENCODE A MESSAGE OR PRESS 'D' TO DECODE A MESSAGE");
        ch = (char) obj.read();

        if ((ch == 'e') || (ch == 'E')) {
            ed.encode();
        } else if ((ch == 'd') || (ch == 'D')) {
            ed.decode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is the output buffer in BlueJ terminal is limited by default. I did find these instructions that suggest you can lift the limit: In the BlueJ terminal window Go to `Options` and turn on `Unlimited Buffering`.